Jetpack Compose Navigation navigate build backstack when navigating
I have the following nested graph:
@Serializable private data object Onboarding
@Serializable private data object OnboardingScreen1
@Serializable private data object OnboardingScreen2
@Serializable private data object OnboardingScreen3 
@Serializable private data object OnboardingScreen4 

navigation<Onboarding>(
  startDestination = OnboardingScreen1,
) {
  composable<OnboardingScreen1> {}
  composable<OnboardingScreen2> {}
  composable<OnboardingScreen3> {}
  composable<OnboardingScreen4> {}
}

I know that I can use navHostController.navigate(Onboarding) to navigate to that graph and then the startDestination, in my case OnboardingScreen1 will be opened. From 1 you can navigate to 2, from 2 to 3 and so on.
How can I pre build the navigation stack though? Let's say the user opens the app again and then I want to restore where the user was last time and then you should start already on OnboardingScreen3 and if you press back you end up on 2, etc?

This would go agains the user's expectation. If they close the app they expect a clean start the next time they open it. That's different from just switching to another app and returning (i.e. putting the app into the Recents screen), that should restore the app in the state it was left (unless the OS decided that it needs to kill the app to free resources). But that is provided out-of-the-box, you do not do anything special to achieve that. I wouldn't recommend trying to recreate the state when the app was closed, though.
